# Third-party AC adapter for Acer Veriton L460 desktop causes fans to continuously run at full speed, even when system is powered off

Tags: power-supply, desktop, fan

I'm not sure this is the the right place to be asking but it seemed like the best option.

I acquired an **Acer Veriton L460 (Ultra SFF Desktop)** which requires an AC converter of *19V 17.1A* so I purchased a *Lite On* one of the same specifications.

It fits fine and works fine except that the two small fans do NOT shut off.

As long as it's plugged in, they are constantly running on high. I know for a fact the computer is off and they're on high.

It doesn't matter what it's doing, the fans are on unless power is cut. I'm not familiar with any BIOS settings that would do this, but I went through and didn't see anything.

I have no other AC adapter to test this with without shelling out another $20. It's not a problem for those who don't care about the noise but that it would be on 24/7 isn't preferable and that it's doing this at all is somewhat concerning.

Runs very cool though. Any insight or direction would be appreciated. Running a fresh OS install.